# Command line options using python argparse module

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

In my program, there are 2 command line options `a1 or a2` and `b1 or b2`. If user wants to use this prog, he/she should use one of these options. For instance,

```
./script.py -a1 val  -b1 val2
```

or

```
./script.py -a1 val -b2 val2
```

or

```
./script.py -a2 val -b1 val2
```

or

```
./script.py -a2 val -b2 val2
```

So he/she can use one of these options a1|a2 or b1|b2. How can handle this command line arguments and get these values  using argparse module ?

And other options is that program gives 3 options to the user. -a1, -a2 and -a3. But -a1 is taking 4 values like below,

```
./script.py -a1 val1 val2 val3 val4
```

and -a2 is taking 2 values like below,

```
./script.py -a2 val1 val2
```

and -a3 is taking 1 value like below,

```
./script.py -a3 val1
```

So i want to develop programs that handle these command line options and values, how can i achieve these using `argparse` module ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to add two [mutually-exclusive groups](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion), both `required=True`.  `a1` cannot be present with `a2`, likewise for the `b` groups.

If they are both `required`, then you must get exactly one of `a`, and exactly one of `b`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group1.add_argument('--a1')
group1.add_argument('--a2')
#likewise for group2
```

Comment: So how can i handle -a1 value ? As you said it can't be used both -a1 and -a2 with this situtation, but how can i handle -a1 or -a2 values ?

Comment: @user2424797 I'm not getting what you're asking.